# Как с помощью js добавить новый класс css при условии что свойство css содержит нужное значение

Tags: javascript, css

Есть элемент у которого плавно увеличивается ширина.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить другому css классу новый класс, когда width будет равен 25%, 50%, 75% и т.д.

Подскажите мою ошибку, пожалуйста

```
const line = document.querySelector('.app-line');
const point = document.querySelector('.app-point-big');
if (line.style.width === 0) {
    point.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

Comment: Можно код увеличения ширины?

Comment: К вопросу об ошибке, отдельно замечу, что line.style.width вероятно возвращает строку "0px", а не число 0. Лучше использовать line.offsetWidth